# enable the merge option in gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab

We are having two repositories in `Gitlab`.

When we edit some changes in the `repository` , it asks to initiate a `merge` request before committing the code

[image]

We have another repository where the option "Start a new merge request with these changes" is not enabled for commit changes

[image]

The `protected branch` configuration for both the repositories are as follows:

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions to enable the merge option in second repository ?

Comment: Have you check the protected branch configuration ?

Comment: Thank you . You helped to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Orel for your hint on the `protected branch` configuration.

Changing the `Allowed to merge` option to `Developers+Maintainers` and `Allowed to Push` to `None` resolved the issue for me

[image]